# Tabletop detection returned error code 2

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi.
I am running ROS Fuerte on Ubuntu 12.04.

I am trying to do a simulation of tabletop manipulation on gazebo, but it seems like it is not working, creating this error when I try to run the pick_and_place_tutorial.cpp (from the pick and place manager tutorial).

```
[ERROR] [1340293467.632676925, 53.720000000]: Tabletop detection returned error code 2
```

Can someone help me figure out this problem?

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36989/tabletop-detection-returned-error-code-2/) by [joey0702](https://answers.ros.org/users/2681/joey0702/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-06-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

IIRC, this usually means that either tabletop detection didn't find the table top, or no objects on the table (there should be more messages in the log to tell you that). The best thing to do is to visualize the point cloud you give to tabletop detection and see whether the table plane is clearly visible and also the biggest plane in the point cloud.

I had this problem a lot when I used a simulated Kinect, and it turned out that there is a bug on integrated Intel chipsets simulating the Kinect output, so the point cloud was all wrong, and the table couldn't be detected.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2012-06-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [iran](https://answers.ros.org/users/3476/iran/) on 2013-02-18**:
Hi, I am using the same package (pick and place tutorial) and I receive the same error. I visualize the point clouds in rviz, and the table plane was the biggest detected plane, Do you have any guess that what else can be a problem? Thank you.